# Proving that $\lambda\mapsto \chi^\lambda(C)/f^\lambda$ is a polynomial

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory

Let $\lambda$ be a partition of $n$ and $\chi^\lambda$ be the character of $S_n$ associated to it. Given any conjugacy class $C$, I want to prove that
$$\lambda\mapsto \frac{\chi^\lambda(C)}{f^\lambda}=\frac{\chi^\lambda(C)}{\chi^\lambda(\text{id})}=\frac{\chi^\lambda(C)}{\dim\chi^\lambda}$$
is a polynomial.

This was affirmed without proof in [1] (Proposition 2.9). The article refers to [2] for a proof. In [2] the proof is not straightforward at all (at least for a undergraduate). I think that, since we want to prove something weaker it should be easier.

[1] Eskin, Alex, and Andrei Okounkov. "Asymptotics of numbers of branched coverings of a torus and volumes of moduli spaces of holomorphic differentials." Inventiones Mathematicae 145.1 (2001): 59-103.

[2] Kerov, Serguei. "Polynomial functions on the set of Young diagrams." CR Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. I Math. 319 (1994): 121-126.

Comment: I don't see your claim in https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006171 . Is the published version that much different?

Comment: Oh! Are you saying that $\chi^\lambda\left(C\right) / \dim \chi^\lambda$ is a polynomial in $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n$ where $\lambda$ is ranging over partitions of length $\leq n$ ? I think I am used to a different notion of "polynomial functions of partitions" (or maybe not so different but just differently defined).

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes! I am saying that it is polynomial in $\lambda_1,\dotsc,\lambda_n$.

Comment: It makes no sense to fix $C$. How does $C$ vary with $\lambda$? For instance, do we fix the number of cycles of length $\geq 2$ and let the number of fixed points vary?

Comment: $C$ does not vary with $\lambda$. We are interested in the function whose input is a representation of $S_4$ and the output is the value of the character of that representation evaluated in $C$. (This is the function $\lambda\mapsto \chi^\lambda(C)$.) The reason for considering $\chi^\lambda(C)/f^\lambda$ is that, while $\lambda\mapsto \chi^\lambda(C)$ is not symmetric, $\lambda\mapsto\chi^\lambda(C)/f^\lambda$ is shifted symmetric (symmetric in the $\lambda_i-i$ variables).

Comment: It seems to me that you want to find a polynomial with a finite number of specified values, whose existence is no problem.

Comment: @RichardStanley Actually, it is not a finite number. If $C$ is a conjugacy class of $S_n$, it is also naturally a conjugacy class of $S_m$ for $m\geq n$. That allows us to use an infinite number of $\lambda_i$. Thats why we say that this function is in $\Lambda^*$ and not in $\Lambda^*_n$ (this are the shifted symmetric analogues to the algebra of symmetric functions and the ring of symmetric polynomials in $n$ variables).

Comment: I see. If you fix $\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\dots$ and let $\lambda_1$ vary so that you get a partition of $n$, then there are a couple of references in the Answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258451/some-irreducible-characters-of-the-symmetric-group-s-n.

Comment: I have already searched MacDonald's book for answers and didn't found much. Also, Garsia - Goupil's character polynomial measure (in a neatly way, I have to say) how $\chi^\lambda(C)$ changes when $C$ changes, not when $\lambda$ changes. 

I think the main study about this is [2] but the (sketch of) proof given there seems way too bizarre for me.

Comment: In fact, I think I could use MacDonald's formula (7.4) $\chi^\lambda=\det(\eta_{\lambda_i+j-i})$ to proceed in a similar fashion to the proof that the Schur functions are in $\Lambda$. However, Macdonald's definition of $\eta$ does not make sense to me. He defines it to be $\eta_n=\chi^{(n)}$. But that is always $1$! Isn't it?

Comment: Is Theorem 2.6 in [Valentin Féray, *Stanley’s formula for characters of the symmetric group*, Ann. Comb., 13(4) : 453--461](http://sci-hub.tw/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00026-009-0038-5) what you are looking for? (I am a bit confused by the various things being equated.) If so, this still leaves the question of finding it *proven* anywhere, as for some reason the reference is missing.

Comment: @darijgrinberg this theorem surely implies what I want! I'll try to find a reference. In any case, this theorem proves WAY more than I need. I think Macdonald's formula may solve it with less work. Have you understood it?